# SonarQube PHP Quality Profile differences: PHP CodeSniffer vs Sonar Way

Tags: php, zend-framework, sonar-runner, software-quality, sonarqube

Sonarqube offers different quality profiles for checking php code. We are wondering what the "best" profile would be for a Zend 1 application and what the main differences are.

The profiles which are currently available are:

- All PHP CodeSniffer (581 Rules)
- All PHPMD (25 rules)
- Pear profile (125 rules)
- Sonar way (66 rules)
- Zend profile (26 rules)

We are using sonarqube 4.

Comment: I can't answer your question because I'm no PHP expert :-), but I'm definitely eager to read the answers! Nobody from the PHP community really ever helped us spending time to define those quality profiles, so we'd be happy to have some PHP gurus come and help us on this task.

Comment: To bad on one is responding...

Comment: As of this forums post of 2013, this does not seem to be possible: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Associate-multiple-profiles-to-a-single-project-td5016870.html